# библиотека Rxjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

в чем отличие mergeMap() от flatMap()? 
mergeMap() нужен для слияния потока или как?

Comment: Вроде `mergeMap` и `flatMap` это одно и то же, по крайней мере [здесь](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) так написано

Comment: я так и не понял, что делает flatMap. если вам не трудно не могли бы разъяснить, все что я понял это то что он берет поток производит какие  то преобразования и добавляет к потоку и наверно я ошибаюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) берёт поток элементов (`Observable`) и функцию, которая каждому элементу из потока сопоставляет другой поток элементов, применяет эту функцию к каждому элементу из первого потока, и возвращает новый поток, в который будут попадать все элементы из всех новых потоков (то есть потоков, которые были получены путём применения функции к элементам первого потока).

На картинке это выглядит примерно так. Здесь верхняя линия это первый поток, цветные кружочки это элементы первого потока, в скобках у `FlatMap` стоит функция, которая принимает элемент первого потока (кружочек) и возвращает новый поток (поток ромбиков). Оператор `FlatMap` возвращает новый поток (нижняя линия), в который попадают все элементы из новых потоков (потоков ромбиков).

[image: механим работы <code>Observable</code>]

---

Вот ещё пример. Предположим, у нас есть поток url-адресов:

```
let observable = Observable.of('yandex.ru', 'google.ru');
```

и мы хотим получить поток ссылок, которые встречаются на этих страницах. Предположим, что у нас есть функция, которая принимает url и возвращает поток ссылок по этому url:

```
function getLinks(url: string): Observable<string> {
    ...
}
```

Тогда искомый поток всех ссылок на всех страницах можно получить используя оператор `flatMap`:

```
let allLinks = urls.flatMap(url => getLinks(url));
```